# What champions can break out of suppression or use abilities while suppressed?

Tags: league-of-legends

With the v1.0.0.111 patch notes it is mentioned that Tryndamere had a bug where he couldn't use his ult during suppression. This sounded weird to me since I was under the idea that suppression was a stun that you couldn't cleanse out of or use abilities while suppressed. Looking around the Internet I can't seem to find a hard defined rule for when a champion may get out of this or use his ability, some champs can just do it with some abilities but I can't find a complete list. So which champion abilities can be used while suppressed?

Comment: Well RIOT confuse me. They introduced surpression for the entire reason of stopping summoners use skills. What was the damn point then, they should have just left it as a stun. :/ Looking into it.

Comment: Yeah I'm greatly confused by it to. I read somewhere that there was a few others that could do it so that's why I was wondering. I'd like to try to find the reason for the exceptions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppression a stun which you cannot cleanse out of. It is also unaffected by merc treads / any CC reductions, such as Irelia's passive. The only two ways to get out of it are either the caster gets interrupted or you use the active on quicksilver sash.

The suppression acts as a **normal stun** +  **locks all summoner spells** (flash, cleanse)

The stun part of the suppression stops champions from using active skills (*as of 16th Feb 2011*), **with the exceptions of**:

- Gangplank - [Remove Scurvey](http://leaguecraft.com/spell/Remove+Scurvy)
- Alistar - [Unbreakable Will](http://leaguecraft.com/spell/Unbreakable+Will)
- Tryndamere - [Undying Rage](http://leaguecraft.com/spell/Undying+Rage) (*Tryndamere will
  remain suppressed for the duration, just
  not die*)

Passive abilities will kick in, such as Anviva's egg.

Comment: But as implied in the patch notes, Tryndamere can apparently use his ult while suppressed. I'm wondering why this seems to be the exception to the rule and if there are other exceptions.

Comment: @The Jug Edited after some research

Comment: What about Olaf's ult?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that Tryndamere's ult is the **exception**, not the rule, as it is one of the few (the only?) abilities that can be used during hard CC (Fear, Stun, Taunt, etc. Suppression counts as one of these).

I think it's important to note that Tryndamere's ult won't *break* the suppression, which will continue for its standard duration, but merely prevent him from dying (as normal). It's the same effect if you're in a regular stun.

In game terms, the only real way to get out of suppression is with the help of another champion -- namely, one with a forced movement ability. Janna's Maelstrom and Gragas' Barrel, as well as a few knockups, like Janna's tornado, will break the suppression.

Alternatively, silencing or otherwise interrupting the suppressor's channel works well too.

Comment: Apparently Scurvy cancels like a QSS.

Comment: Good point. Gangplank's "Remove Scurvy" is also designed to be used during hard CC effects.

Answer (score 1):

While this is the exception, there are ways some champions can cheat and out of suppression, and these are the champions with a built-in teleport, blink, or jump (Ezreal, Trista, Kassadin, to name a few).

Say a Warwick attempts to gank mid, and kill Tristana. If Tristana rocket jumps back to her tower *exactly* at the same time WW ults her, she will rocket jump away, and Warwick will teleport to where she jumped FROM. Trist will be suppressed, but will be jumping through the air for half the duration, and take no damage from the other half (as WW's attacks require melee range).

Note that of the three champions that have a suppress (Warwick, Malzahar, and Urgot) this is only super-effective against Warwick (as his requires melee range). It is effective against Malzahar if you get out of the range of his ult, and doesn't work against Urgot.

Comment: blinks don't "break out of suppression" and cannot "be used while suppressed", which is what the OP asked in his question.

Comment: It doesn't really answer his question at all though.  He's asking about abilities that can be used **during** suppression or abilities that can break out of suppression.  That is simply using an ability before suppression to take slightly less damage.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone can if you buy Quicksilver Sash!